# How can I use router instead of app in express?

Tags: express

I watched vimedo video(https://vimeo.com/56166857) and followed his direction to build my web application more module like.

```
// project/signup/index.js
var express= require('express');
var app = module.exports= express();
app.set('views', __dirname);
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.get('/', function(req,res){
  res.render('form');
});

// project/app.js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var login= require('./login');
var signup = require('./signup');
app.use('/login', login);
app.use('/signup',signup);
module.exports=app;
var port = 4100;
app.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('we are connecting server at '+ port);
})
```

However, I want to use `router` instead of `app`, so I want my code to look like this,

```
// project/signup/index.js
..
router.get('/', function(req,res){
  res.render('form');
});
```

I added `var router = express.Router();` and `module.exports=router;` inside of index.js but did not have any luck.
Did I miss something in here?

Answer (score 0):

Your `require()` path seems wrong. You should use `var signup = require('./signup/index');`
And, mostly express apps I've seen use following project structure:
App dir
__app.js
__/routes
____login.js
____signup.js
__/views
____login.jade

```
// project/routes/signup.js
const router = require('express').Router();
//...
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send("signup!");
});

module.exports = router;

// project/app.js
const signup = require('./routes/signup');
//...
app.use('/signup', signup);
```

Comment: I am trying little bit different. I am making mine as module